# How to save .shp with layers 'baked' in with QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

I'm having no problem applying labels to the shapefile I'm working on in QGIS, but I can't seem to save the new shapefile with the layers 'baked in' for uploading to Mapbox, and then styling.

I've tried lots of saving options after I apply the labels, but can't seem to get them to show up when I import it into Mapbox Studio. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels are just a styling that you see in QGIS. Their existence let alone position and other parameters are not saved with the shapefile.

You need to look at labelling in Mapbox entirely separate from QGIS. Here are some links to documentation to help you:

- https://www.mapbox.com/blog/placing-labels/
- https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-labels/